# Electron - mainWindow.show() doesnt work inside ipcMain

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm setting the event from my application on ipcMain like this:

```
ipcMain.on('remind', () => {
    console.log('remind fired');
    mainWindow.show();
});
```

console.log is fired but mainWindow is still hidden. I have the same functionality in tray:

```
tray.on('click', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
});
```

...and it works like a charm. I'm working on Windows 10 and I think it worked before on Mac but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't destroy the window instead of hiding it?

Comment: I'm sure, I can still get this app to the top with tray